# Record voices in online conference when using AirPods

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, airpods, recording

I often use Audacity to have voice recordings of online conferences (mainly Zoom). With my Macbook Air's speaker on, by default both the conference sound and my voice are recorded through the internal mic.

Now I have to wear AirPods during such conferences. Can I still record both together?
After googling around, it doesn't look easy to me.

For instance, my Mac has only one headset port and cannot use a loopback cable, which I don't have or like. And audacity seems to have a problem recording my voice input via AirPods: it does identify AirPods as an input device but cannot get the voice.

Comment: This is because the input device can only work with one application at once.  You need something like [Audio Hijack](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/)